# Topic not present in metadata after 60000ms

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Use case scenario :
I am trying to make sure that in case the broker (one of bootstrap ones) which producer connects to in order to fetch the meta data is not available, then after blocking it for `max.block.ms` it should retry (atleast 3 retries or until let's say `metadata.fetch.timeout.ms` is reached - this property no longer exists) with the other brokers available in the nodes list.
Properties like `retries` and `retry.backoff.ms` is applicable for the sender thread.
Can somebody help me configure the Kafka properties for my use case scenario?
I believe the properties that will help in this situation are
`metadata.max.age.ms`, `request.timeout.ms`

Answer (score 0):

You can try below settings to ensure that the producer client retries connecting to different brokers in the list if the initial connection to the bootstrap broker fails

```
       bootstrap.servers=broker1:9092,broker2:9092,broker3:9092
metadata.max.age.ms=5000
retries=3
retry.backoff.ms=1000
request.timeout.ms=30000
connections.max.idle.ms=10000
```

I do not believe Kafka has a particular property to configure number of retries for metadata fetching. The `metadata.max.age.ms` and `connections.max.idle.ms` properties indirectly influence this behavior.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your input, let me give it a try. So, if a connection is idle for more than 10 seconds, it will try connecting with another broker right? What's the default value for it

Comment: Also just putting my thoughts out loud, won't setting connections.max.idle.ms to 10 seconds increase a lot of socket connection resets?

Comment: Yes you’re right. Setting connections.max.idle.ms to a certain value in Kafka will cause connections to be closed if they are idle for longer than that time. The default value for connections.max.idle.ms in Kafka is typically set to 9 minutes (540000 milliseconds)

Comment: Yes setting to a low value such as 10 seconds will likely increase socket connection resets. I’d suggest you use the default value I shared or higher than that